# How to set value of cterm to both bold and underline?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

Currently, my vimrc has

```
set cursorline
hi CursorLine cterm=underline ctermbg=none ctermfg=none
```

I want to be set `cterm` to both `underline` and `bold`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Vim has excellent help files.

I had no idea what the answer was to this question but I found it in one minute:

1. `:h cterm` (don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet)
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> for auto-completion to see some choices
3. *highlight-cterm* sounds promising so tab over to it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Hmm, *cterm={attr-list}* and *See above for the description of attr-list*
5. That last "attr-list" is highlighted as a tag so put cursor over it and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

And voila..

```
attr-list is a comma separated list (without spaces) of the following items (in any order):
        bold
        underline
        ..etc..
```

So `cterm=underline,bold` is the answer.

Vim has excellent help files.